# python dictionary with value having multiple parameters

Tags: python, dictionary

i have a problem in fetching values from a dictionary. di is a dictionary.

```
for key in di.keys()
    print("key is = %s" %key)
for value in di.values()
    print("value is = %s" %value)
```

it gives output as

```
key is = 1
```

and

```
value is = xyz=0 | pqr=70 | abc=300
```

i want all 3 values(0,70,300) above in separate variables. i am not able to do

```
di['xyz']
```

since xyz is itself in a value.
how to fetch all these values?
is it a nested dictionary?

Comment: that's not valid python

Comment: What does `di` look like, what's the format of the data?

Comment: di's structure i don't know.all i know it is mapping (int->capacity) mapping a node to its capacity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the looks of it, this is your dictionary

```
>>> di = {'1': 'xyz=0 | pqr=70 | abc=300'}
```

Or maybe `{1: 'xyz=0 | pqr=70 | abc=300'}`, but you weren't very clear in the question so I'll assume the first.

It's weird that you would have this as a dictionary, so I won't bother trying to think about why that may be, instead I'll just show you how you could build what you want from the string `'xyz=0 | pqr=70 | abc=300'`

```
>>> di['1'].split(' | ')
['xyz=0', 'pqr=70', 'abc=300']
```

Splits by the vertical bars

```
>>> [x.split('=') for x in di['1'].split(' | ')]
[['xyz', '0'], ['pqr', '70'], ['abc', '300']]
```

Splits by equal signs to make key-pair lists

```
>>> dict(x.split('=') for x in di['1'].split(' | '))
{'xyz': '0', 'abc': '300', 'pqr': '70'}
```

Builds a `dict` out of that

```
>>> di = dict(x.split('=') for x in di['1'].split(' | '))
>>> di['xyz']
'0'
```

and now you can access it like `di['xyz']`